# QuickBooks Online 1000 results issue

Tags: quickbooks-online

QuickBooks Online only supports retrieving 1000 results of a query as per https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/00300_query_operations. Currently I am specifying toDate and fromDate parameters to get around this. Is there any other way to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use pagination to traverse the full record set: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/00300_query_operations/0100_key_topics#Pagination

Comment: How would I implement this in code? I'm using C# to construct my queries.

Comment: In the .NET SDK, FindAll accepts StartPosition and MaxResults as parameters